# \nameref : how to get counter's label value instead of section name

Tags: cross-referencing, lists

Hi I build a customer list environment with a counter, and I'd like to be able to reference the name the label associated with the counter. The code below produces an output similar to this:

**Requirements**

- REQ1 Requirement one
- REQ2 Requirement two

**Another Section**

- We want read "Requirement One" here : *Requirements*.
- But instead we get the section name!

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bookmarks, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=black]{hyperref}

\newcounter{reqcount}
\renewcommand{\thereqcount}{\textbf{REQ\arabic{reqcount}}}

\newenvironment{nfrequirements}
  { \begin{list}{\textbf{\thereqcount}}{\usecounter{reqcount}} }
  { \end{list} }

\newcommand{\requirement}[1]{
  \item \textbf{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\thereqcount \quad #1}
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Requirements Section}
\begin{requirements}
  \requirement{Requirement one} \label{req_one} \\
  description
  \requirement{Requirement two} \label{req_two} \\
  description
\end{requirements}

\section{Another Section}
We want read "Requirement One" here : \nameref{req_one}.
But instead we get the section name.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect that zref can do what you want.

Comment: A similar question was asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767389/referencing-a-theorem-like-environment-by-its-name might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 11):

Set \@currentlabelname:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\requirement}[1]{%
  \item
  \def\@currentlabelname{#1}%
  \textbf{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\thereqcount \quad #1}
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite the same thing, but consider the following:

```
\newenvironment{requirements}
  { \begin{list}{\textbf{\thereqcount}}{} }
  %{ \begin{list}{\textbf{\thereqcount}}{\usecounter{reqcount}} }
  { \end{list} }
\newcommand{\requirement}[1]{
  \refstepcounter{reqcount}
  \item \textbf{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{\thereqcount \quad #1}
}
```

The inclusion of `\refstepcounter` means that the value of the `reqcount` counter becomes the thing that `\label` now picks up (rather than the argument of `\section`, which will have been the last thing that invoked `\refstepcounter`).

After this, `\ref{req_one}` expands to "REQ1".  Getting `\nameref` to do the same is presumably not far away (ie, exercise for reader territory!)

Comment: Responding to Ulrike's suggestion: `\refstepcounter` ultimately results in setting `\@currentlabel` (though with hyperref being part of the game, that's a biiig 'ultimately').  I suspect that `\@currentlabelname` is a hyperref addition, to support `\nameref`.